# Chrome 35 Broke PHP get_browser

Tags: php, google-chrome, browser-detection

With the recent upgrade to chrome 35 the get_browser can no longer see the browser version. Is anyone else having this problem? If so, any thoughts on how to fix this?

Current output for Chrome Version 35.*

```
    Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => �^mozilla/5\.0 \(.*mac os x 10_9.*\) applewebkit/.* \(khtml, like gecko\).*chrome/.*safari/.*$�
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (*Mac OS X 10_9*) AppleWebKit/* (KHTML, like Gecko)*Chrome/*Safari/*
    [parent] => Chrome Generic
    [platform] => MacOSX
    [platform_version] => 10.9
    [comment] => Chrome Generic
    [browser] => Chrome
    [cssversion] => 1
    [version] => 0.0
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 0
    [alpha] => 
    [beta] => 
    [win16] => 
    [win32] => 
    [win64] => 
    [frames] => 
    [iframes] => 
    [tables] => 
    [cookies] => 
    [backgroundsounds] => 
    [javascript] => 
    [vbscript] => 
    [javaapplets] => 
    [activexcontrols] => 
    [ismobiledevice] => 
    [issyndicationreader] => 
    [crawler] => 
    [aolversion] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with an updated browscap.ini file. Update your browscap.ini file

http://browscap.org/

You can test the Chrome 35 user agent here

http://browscap.org/ua-lookup

Comment: Thanks - I just did an update to the browscap.ini file, restarted apache and still getting the same output. It simply does not want to see the version. Tried in other browsers to make sure the update did not break anything, and all other browsers seem to be working fine. Thoughts?

Comment: Just tested in a php 5.4 box using the full_php_bowscap.ini file. The results are correct. Maybe your user agent is different? This is mine Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36

Comment: Full is the one I used as well. My user agent is: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36

Comment: Looks like it eventually started working. It ended up being a page caching issue. Thanks for your help!